# Segmentation fault when running bib2x

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm working on an unfamiliar machine and I am trying to get a program called [bib2x](http://www.xandi.eu/bib2x/about.html) to work. Unfortunately, when I run the program, I keep getting a segmentation fault. My (limited) experience and research leads me to believe that this was a result of some kind of memory error, but I'm not sure how to proceed or how to fix the problem.

I've run the program accessing files that the user account definitely has permission to access. Any ideas on how I ought proceed?

Sorry if this is vague. It's a vague problem and I'm confused about what to do next.

Comment: To better understand what the problem is, you can run: `strace <command>`. If you're lucky, the output from strace will provide you with more information on how to correct your problem (assuming that this is not a real bug with bib2x).

Comment: I would consider almost any segfault "a real bug". Exceptions are rare.

Comment: But it could be helpful for discovering a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Does the program run at all (e.g., can you run something like

`bib2x -V`

and report the version)?

It's going to be a bit difficult to debug that problem on an unfamiliar machine, without the [bib2x source](http://www.xandi.eu/bib2x/download.html) and a way to recompile it. You could try reinstalling it (it looks like executables are available for several platforms [here](http://www.xandi.eu/bib2x/download.html)), or recompiling it if that's an option.

Can you temporarily just use the [online bib2x converter](http://www.bibtex.org/Convert/)?

Comment: It appears to be GPLv2, so the source should be available.

Comment: Yeah, it does report the version. I tried compiling the script and at make it outputs an error:
`(atomdatabinary.cxx:117:39: error: 'memcpy' was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [atomdatabinary.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/alex/bib2x-0.9.0/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1 `
I'm guessing this won't be an easy error and I should look for an alternative solution? I can post the whole output if it would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post some details about how you're using bib2x? What version is it? What usage causes the segfault? What platform are you running on?